# d3.js: Does force layout only work with circles?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm using d3.force to setup nodes and have links connecting each of the nodes. It all works great when I'm using circles as the nodes:

```
  var nodes = [{ title: "ABC", group: 1 }, { title: "DEF", group: 1 }, { title: "Blah", group: 1 }];
  var links = [{ source: 0, target: 1 }, { source: 0, target: 2 }];

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(function(d) {
      console.log(d);
      return 250 * Math.random() + 100;
    })
    .size([r, r]);

  force.links(links)
    .nodes(nodes)
    .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll("line.link")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", 1);

  var node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 15)
    .call(force.drag);
```

However, if I change the nodes to use "g", it stops working:

```
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 15)
    .call(force.drag);

  var circle = node.append("circle")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      var b = Math.floor(255 * Math.random()),
          rgba = "rgba(0, 0, " + b + ", 0.7)";

      return rgba;
    })
    .attr("r", 15);
```

I can see the circles being added to the g elements but they're not where they're supposed to be and they are not connected by the links.

I'd really like to use "g" elements as the nodes so that I can add text to it. Does anyone have any insight to this?

Alternatively, if there's a way to add text to a "circle" element. I'm also open to that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try consolidating this into one statement, with the call at the end:

```
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .append("circle")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
       var b = Math.floor(255 * Math.random()),
       rgba = "rgba(0, 0, " + b + ", 0.7)";
       return rgba;
     })
    .attr("r", 15)
    .call(force.drag);
```

Then you can attach other elements, such as text.

Comment: Ahh i'm still having trouble with adding the texts. So this works fine with adding a "g" wrapper around the circle, however, when I try to append text to "g", it breaks the force directed graph. Is this even possible to add text to a force directed graph?